# How to navigate to a Kotlin type declaration from a variable with an inferred type in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
val request = buildRequest()
```

**Problem:** I want to see what the type of `request` is and navigate to its declaration.

I can find out the type by hovering the variable or using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>, but I haven't found an easy way to navigate to the type itself. <kbd>command + click</kbd> doesn't work here.

**Question:** How to navigate to the type declaration of a variable whose type is inferred?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> keyboard shortcut?

This tip for Windows or Linux users.

[image: Context menu]

[image: Result of Type declaration choose]

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users

<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> - find out the type

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> - go to type declaration

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Mac, try <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>